# How do I do @InjectMocks with Scala

Tags: scala, mockito

I have the following code...

```
class MyClassImpl extends MyClass {
  @Autowired private val myService: MyService = null
  ...
  override def deleteItem(id: String): Boolean = {
    return myService.delete(id)
  }
}
```

So I want to make a simple unit test to make sure it is calling the service.

```
@RunWith(classOf[MockitoJUnitRunner])
class MyClassImplTest(){
  @Spy
  @InjectMocks
  var myClass: MyClassImpl = _

  @Mock
  var myService: myService = _

  @Test
  def testRun(){
      doReturn(true).when(myService).delete(anyString())
      myClass.deleteItem("");
      verify(myService, times(1)).delete(anyString())
  }
}
```

But when I run the test inside `MyClassImplTest myService` has a mocked object. However, inside `MyClassImpl` it is still `null`, so I get an NPE.

Can someone see what I am missing? Is this an idiosyncrasy of Scala?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? It seems clear that `myClass` is not actually getting `myService` injected, but we should be clear that is the NPE in question.

Comment: Not really because the class names would be different but I can tell you that it is an NPE `java.lang.NullPointerException` coming from the `myService.delete(id)` when I debug I see `myService` is null

Comment: Actually what is weird is I have one variable that is fine and one that isn't let me expand

Comment: Dope typo! No it is easy to solve ;-)